# Dynamic string type in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have this array of pages in react.

```
export const pages: Page[] = [
  { path: "/", exact: true, component: PageHome },
  { path: "/home2", exact: true, component: PageHome2 },
  { path: "/blog", component: Blog},
  { path: "/blog/post/:id, component: SinglePost}
];
```

and maping this array to define Routes.

```
{pages.map(({ component, path, exact }) => (
  <Route
    key={path}
    component={component}
    exact={!!exact}
    path={path}
  />
  )
)}
```

I have Page type defined as

```
export interface LocationStates {
  "/"?: {},
  "/home2"?: {},
  "/blog"?: {},
  "/blog/post/:id"?: {}
}

export type PathName = keyof LocationStates;

export interface Page {
  path: PathName;
  exact?: boolean;
  component: ComponentType<Object>;
  isProtected?: boolean;
}
```

Everything is working fine except `/blog/post/:id` route when i use this route in any button or link which has the href prop of type `PathName` defined in types page. When I use this route in button i have to replace `:id` to hard value or a variable due to which I think type not matches to `PathName`.
How I can solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

I have searched about it but was not able to found anything about this.

Anyhelp will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [This](https://catchts.com/useful-patterns#builder) article might be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace the route:
`/blog/post/${1}`
```